# MS-SQL getting case specific values

Tags: sql-server, loops, variables, case-statement

We have a table LogicalTableSharing as follows:

[image]

For a specific requirement, we need to take PhysicalCompany of each TableCode into a variable.
We tried a case-based query as follows:

```
declare @tablecode varchar(50)
declare @inputcompany varchar(50)

declare @query nvarchar(2500)


set @inputcompany= 91


set @query = '
select '''+@inputcompany+''' AS inputcompany,
       CASE WHEN lts.TableCode = ''tsctm005'' THEN lts.PhysicalCompany ELSE NULL END as tsctm005_company,
       CASE WHEN lts.TableCode = ''tccom000'' THEN lts.PhysicalCompany ELSE NULL END as tccom000_company
from LogicalTableSharing lts
where  lts.LogicalCompany = '''+@inputcompany+'''
'
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

which obviously gives the result as

[image]

The desired output is

[image]

What is the right approach?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL here, that's wide open to injection?

Comment: Do **not** post images of tables. Paste the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text** into the post.

Comment: 1) Why you're using a dynamic SQL while it's not needed here? 2) Why you're using `THEN lts.PhysicalCompany ELSE NULL END` while you can just type `THEN lts.PhysicalCompany END`

Comment: 1)inputcompany is not to be hardcoded actually, it is a variable to be taken from outside 2) The NULL is to be replaced with some values, by default it is taking NULL so kept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try subqueries in a `FROM`-less `SELECT`. For performance you want an index on `(logicalcompany, tablecode)` (or the other way round depending on which is more selective).

```
SELECT @inputcompany inputcompany,
       (SELECT TOP 1
               physicalcompany
               WHERE logicalcompany = @inputcompany
                     AND tablecode = 'tsctm005'
               ORDER BY <some criteria>) tsctm005_company,
       (SELECT TOP 1
               physicalcompany
               WHERE logicalcompany = @inputcompany
                     AND tablecode = 'tccom000'
               ORDER BY <some criteria>) tccom000_company;
```

You should find `<some criteria>` to order by in case of multiple possible rows to decide which one takes precedence. Unless you just want a random one possibly each time you run the query another one, that is.

Comment: If you have a `TOP` you really *need* an `ORDER BY`. Any arbitrary row does not give consistent, and therefore reliable, results.

Comment: @Larnu: Fair point, thanks. I should have mentioned that. I edited the answer.